number of ways in which five different employees can sit in four identical offices, where any office may have any number of persons, including zero

If $n$ is number of ways in which five different employees can sit in four indistinguishable offices, where any office may have any number of persons including zero, then $n$ is equal to

My Approach: I solved this using case method
Case $1$: $5,0,0,0\implies 1$ way
Case $2$: $4,1,0,0\implies 5$ ways
Case $3$: $3,2,0,0\implies 10$ ways
Case $4$: $2,2,0,1\implies 15$ ways
Case $5$: $2,1,1,1 \implies 10$ ways
Case $6$: $3,1,1,0 \implies 10$ ways
Hence there are total of $51$ cases
My Doubt: Is this question can be solved using principle of inclusion and exclusion?
Also, how can I solve this question using Stirling function?

See twelvefold way

Your answer is correct, but the simplest tool to use here is formation of unlabeled teams, which, written in factorial form, would be
$\frac{5!}{5!} + \frac{5!}{4!1!} +\frac{5!}{3!2!} + \frac{5!}{3!1!1!}/2! + \frac{5!}{2!2!1!}/2! + \frac{5!}{2!1!1!1!}/3! = 51$
Notice particularly the divisions where teams have identical numbers of people.
If you prefer, you can use the choose function instead, e.g.
$\binom55 + \binom54 + \binom53 + \binom53\binom21/2! +...$
but I feel that less errors will be committed using the factorial form, although it is longer, because it spells out the full details.

Re your doubts

You can use inclusion-exclusion, firstly assuming that the rooms are distinct, and then erasing their identity by dividing by $k!$ where $k$ is the nmber of occupied rooms, and you will have to do it separately for $1,2,3,4$ rooms occupied and add up.

Similarly, Stirling numbers of the second kind, of course, can be used, but again in summation form i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^4{5\brace {k}}$$


So while both these tools are available, I wonder whether they are worthwhile, unless you have a handy table of Stirling numbers with you !

How to use PIE here
We shall compute for $1,2,3,4,5$ boxes full and add them up. Remember that we need to erase the identity of the boxes, so
$\frac{1^5}{1!} + \frac{2^5-\binom21\cdot1^5}{2!} +\frac{3^5-\binom31\cdot2^5+\binom32\cdot1^5}{3!} + \frac{4^5-\binom41\cdot3^5 +\binom42\cdot2^5 -\binom43\cdot1^5}{4!} $
which yields the answer of $\boxed{51}$
You might agree that the first method given was the simplest amd most transparent !

Can you please provide full solution of P.I.E.? If possible so i can understand better

I shall add material about it

@mathophile See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.
